# Xcode refusing to return title bar attribute to window

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I've accidentally unchecked the Title Bar attribute of the main window of an Xcode 8 project. After a while I tried checking it back, but Xcode just shows a "-" sign inside the checkbox for about a second, and then unchecks this attribute again...

[image]

So my app is stuck without the window title bar...

Any ideas what is causing this and for some workaround?

Comment: In the files navigator you can right click the storyboard and then go to "view as..." → "source". There you can search fr the object ID (found in the inspector) and see if you can find any controversial entries. Maybe you can spot something and make a good guess

Comment: when comparing to the source of a properly functioning project, the relevant diff had `frameAutosaveName=""` and `restorable="NO"` attributes... removing them and manually adding `titled="YES"` solved this

Comment: Glad I could help. I made an answer from the comment so you can mark it as correct

Comment: I have the same problem. Simple workaround is just delete window from storyboard and add it again and reconnect with View Controller etc. (rather simple). But what is worse I cannot select also "Full Size Content View" as I have the same minus behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the files navigator and right click you're storyboard. Then hit "view as → source".

Now you can see the raw XML of you're storyboard. Search for your windows object ID (found in the object inspector).

Now check all the attributes and entries of the object in question. Sometimes the XML gets corrected and you might be able to spot something strange there.

You can also compare what happened in a file diff. I'd recommend using local GIT repos anyway.

Comment: fullSizeContentView="YES" or titled="YES" can be set in XML manually but it is odd that it cannot be checked by InterfaceBuilder!

Comment: Is struggle the same bug for a very long time in Xcode. Usually restarting / closing / any reset-ish action helps for me. But yeah, in some cases it just doesn't work